# NSService - items added to the context menu doesn't show up on mac os x

Tags: objective-c, macos, contextmenu, osx-elcapitan, info.plist

I wish that the context menu shows services of my app. For this purpose, I wrote the following code.

According to this example: [Services Implementation Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/SysServices/Articles/providing.html), I created a handlers for my services in AppDelegate class.

```
- (void)ServiceHandler:(NSPasteboard *)pboard userData:(NSString *)data error:(NSString **)error
{
    NSLog(@"I clicked");
}

- (void)ServiceHandler2:(NSPasteboard *)pboard userData:(NSString *)data error:(NSString **)error
{
    NSLog(@"I clicked");
}

- (void)ServiceHandler3:(NSPasteboard *)pboard userData:(NSString *)data error:(NSString **)error
{
    NSLog(@"I clicked");
}
```

Then I set up AppDelegate as service provider in applicationDidFinishLaunching: method and installed a services as follows:

```
 - (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification {   
    [NSApp setServicesProvider:self];
    NSUpdateDynamicServices();
}
```

And then I created all my services in info.plist as follows:

```
<key>NSServices</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>NSKeyEquivalent</key>
            <dict>
                <key>default</key>
                <string>E</string>
            </dict>
            <key>NSMenuItem</key>
            <dict>
                <key>default</key>
                <string>Item 1</string>
            </dict>
            <key>NSMessage</key>
            <string>ServiceHandler</string>
            <key>NSPortName</key>
            <string>MyApp</string>
            <key>NSRequiredContext</key>
            <dict>
                <key>NSApplicationIdentifier</key>
                <string>com.apple.finder</string>
            </dict>
            <key>NSReturnTypes</key>
            <array>
                <string>NSStringPboardType</string>
            </array>
            <key>NSSendFileTypes</key>
            <array>
                <string>public.item</string>
            </array>
            <key>NSServiceDescription</key>
            <string>Description of this service</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>NSKeyEquivalent</key>
            <dict>
                <key>default</key>
                <string>H</string>
            </dict>
            <key>NSMenuItem</key>
            <dict>
                <key>default</key>
                <string>Item 2</string>
            </dict>
            <key>NSMessage</key>
            <string>ServiceHandler3</string>
            <key>NSPortName</key>
            <string>MyApp</string>
            <key>NSRequiredContext</key>
            <dict>
                <key>NSApplicationIdentifier</key>
                <string>com.apple.finder</string>
            </dict>
            <key>NSReturnTypes</key>
            <array>
                <string>NSStringPboardType</string>
            </array>
            <key>NSSendFileTypes</key>
            <array>
                <string>public.item</string>
            </array>
            <key>NSServiceDescription</key>
            <string>Description of this service</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>NSKeyEquivalent</key>
            <dict>
                <key>default</key>
                <string>Z</string>
            </dict>
            <key>NSMenuItem</key>
            <dict>
                <key>default</key>
                <string>Item 3</string>
            </dict>
            <key>NSMessage</key>
            <string>ServiceHandler2</string>
            <key>NSPortName</key>
            <string>MyApp</string>
            <key>NSRequiredContext</key>
            <dict>
                <key>NSApplicationIdentifier</key>
                <string>com.apple.finder</string>
            </dict>
            <key>NSReturnTypes</key>
            <array>
                <string>NSStringPboardType</string>
            </array>
            <key>NSSendFileTypes</key>
            <array>
                <string>com.MyApp.anytype</string>
            </array>
            <key>NSServiceDescription</key>
            <string>Description of this service</string>
        </dict>
    </array>
    <key>UTExportedTypeDeclarations</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>UTTypeConformsTo</key>
            <array>
                <string>public.item</string>
            </array>
            <key>UTTypeDescription</key>
            <string>extension for anytype</string>
            <key>UTTypeIconFile</key>
            <string></string>
            <key>UTTypeIdentifier</key>
            <string>com.MyApp.anytype</string>
            <key>UTTypeReferenceURL</key>
            <string>http://anytype.MyApp.com</string>
            <key>UTTypeTagSpecification</key>
            <dict>
                <key>public.filename-extension</key>
                <array>
                    <string>anytype</string>
                </array>
            </dict>
        </dict>
    </array>
```

I registered my new type of file by:

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/LaunchServices.framework/Support/lsregister -f /path/to/MyApp
```

Of course I ran this command too:

```
/System/Library/CoreServices/pbs -update
/System/Library/CoreServices/pbs -flush
/System/Library/CoreServices/pbs -dump_cache
```

And I tried to debug NSServices by:

```
/Applications/TextEdit.app/Contents/MacOS/TextEdit -NSDebugServices com.MyApp
```

The result of this command was ok.

```
2016-03-14 13:21:16.697 TextEdit[885:6374] NSDebugServices=com.MyApp
Item 1 (com.MyApp) is enabled in the services menu and enabled in the context menu, by the standard Services policy.
Item 2 (com.MyApp) is enabled in the services menu and enabled in the context menu, by the standard Services policy.
Item 3 (com.MyApp) is enabled in the services menu and enabled in the context menu, by the standard Services policy.
```

Everything is enabled and I can see them in preferences with selected checkboxes, but still this items are not visible in context menu. I really don't know where the problem is. Any Ideas ?

EDIT: I changed every **public.item** on **NSFilenamesPboardType** a now is working, but only two of them. I still can't see in context menu service with my own extension. Anybody knows why **public.item** is wrong ?

EDIT2: Solved. I had a problem with identifier of file extension. I changed it and now it works.

Comment: I don't know anything about services but shouldn't the strings with key `NSMessage` be the name of the method, like `messageName:userData:error:`?

Comment: Are the menu items visible in the Finder?

Comment: Yes, they are visible in Finder and checkboxes next to them are selected. According to stack or apple the first part of method is enough, because the rest is always the same.

Comment: Checkboxes in the Finder?

Comment: Yup, these ones :)

Comment: BTW, I have the problem that after changing my services, e.g. the NSPortName or NSMenuItem, the changes would not appear in the Services menu. I resolve this by killing the pbs service, like explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13483800/43615

Comment: How do you debug installing services? I suppose that you build release configuration and install app, right?